# Is there a way that i could move my sword on a dummy in a certain direction using scripting in roblox as its welded together? #robloxstudioscripting

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to move my sword for my dummy figure using Roblox studio scripting, i have started making the animation and noticed it was not in a position that i wanted for making the rest of the animation.

I'm hoping to move the welded sword specifically to the **left a bit** so it looks like both hands are holding the sword, am i able to make this happen using scripting (or through the animation editor).

[here is an image showing what i have done so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SufO1.png)

I'm also very new to scripting in Roblox. Any help will be great!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the position permanently you can change the position of a tool in a Humanoid by either using a plugin like  Tool Grip Editor or manually adjusting the CFrame Grip property of the tool.

If you want to change it dynamically, you can create a Motor6d joint between the sword and the arm, this would need to be created with scripting. You can then, either with an animation or with scripting adjust the position of the sword compared to the arm.

Comment: Thanks!, i found a good tutorial for the animation and managed to get the sword moving

Edit: through this tutorial -> (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlkMmKmyXUA)